# Storyboard segue flips the wrong direction

Tags: xcode4.3, segue

I have a main view controller that calls other storyboard views by swipe gesture... On one of those views, I have a button that calls another views by segue (my button is linked to this modal view) ... when I test it, the screen appears then suddenly turns sideways... I have my "`shoudRotateToInterfaceDirection`" set to

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }
```

which is the same everywhere.. and the other views are working as expected...

the whole app is set the `lanscapeRight` (and is the only direction allowed)...

any clues?

thx

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after doing some testing, it seems that using the "default" presentation is causing the issue... I switched it to "current context" and now it appears fine...